# Why set expiration of cache if can expire with event? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I've seen many short expirations like 30 minutes, 6 hours. I rarely see anything like 7 days, or 30 days. So, if I have a list of categories to cache. Why would I set an expiration on that cache if I can expire the cache when categories are updated via an observer/callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many reasons to expire a cache based on time versus when your data changes. Imagine having a very high traffic website where the data is constantly expiring the cache. Determining what type of cache expiry mechanism to go with depends on how you answer questions like these:

1. Do you want your data to be as up to date as possible?
2. Do you have a very high traffic website/application?
3. Does the data that updates often cause a large amount of cache objects to expire?

If `3` is a big problem for you, expiring based on a time may be your best option. If `2` and `3` are true, then you're going to find you're expiring your caches very often and losing most of the benefit. Obviously is `1` is the most important thing to you, you may need to look at entirely different caching options.

My suggestion is to typically start with the observer/callback approach and as you need to scale you can try expiring based on time if `1` isn't too important or using something more production-ready like [memcached](http://memcached.org/).